# Displaying checkedboxes texts in a message

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm working on a C# windows application project which requires to display the result of five check boxes in a message.After the user checked all he wants ,I have to display what he checked in a message show box. Here is what I did so far :

```
private void Display_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkSkis.Checked == true)
    {
        message = message +chkSkis.Text;
    }

    if (chkGoogles.Checked == true)
    {
        message = message +chkGoogles.Text;
    }
}

private void displayOrderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You chose the following equipments:\n" + message,
                    "Flyers Sports Club");
}
```

Comment: I did declare the variable message = " " at the begining of the class.

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In the message I get just one check box text added and not more.

Comment: If I chose more than one checkbox ,message just displays this one and not other checked ones.

Comment: I would guess that something is resetting `message` to empty and only the last checkbox event populates it.

Comment: That is right ,I'm missing a sort of looping but I can't figure it out .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice to use `StringBuilder`.  In addition, using the code you posted, if the user un-checks a box, you aren't removing those from the string.  I would suggest building the string inside the `displayOrderToolStripMenuItem_Click` event like so:

```
private void displayOrderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    if (chkSkis.Checked == true)
    {
        message.AppendLine(chkSkis.Text);
    }

    if (chkGoogles.Checked == true)
    {
        message.AppendLine(chkGoogles.Text);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("You chose the following equipments:\n" + message.ToString(),
                "Flyers Sports Club");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't give the right results ,here what I got after applying your code :

Comment: You chose the following equipments:Skis Skis Googles

Comment: Oh wait ,I didn't pay attention that put the code in the tool stip ,actually yes it's working now thank you so much :)))